# Parse: Sending Push in App from UITextView pushes empty message

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, uitextview, parse-platform

If I send a Push message from within the App with `sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground` Method with hardcoded text in the "withMessage" part then the push is received on the device.

On the website I can see the successful delivery and the text that I wrote.

Now I changed this to send content from a `UITextView` (like so: `withMessage:pushField.text`).

I can see the text in the log (Xcode) and even `sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground` gives me a "Succeeded" back, but I don't receive any message.
On the website the push is registered but with no message inside the "alert". 
What is wrong here?

Comment: Add your code to your question. Hard to help without it ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doooh my fault. I was resetting the UITextView content before it was pushed. Really stupid :)